# Infinite natural number to form $4n^2+1$ can be divided by $5$ and $13$

Tags: number-theory

Can someone proof with contradiction that there are infinite natural numbers $n$ that $4n^2+1$ can be divided by $5$ and $13$?

Comment: Prove with contradiction*

Comment: I ask with contradiction without proof you replace n with 65n +4 and you are ok

Comment: "Assume that there are only finitely many $n$ such that $4n^2 + 1$ is divisible by $5$ and $13$. Then $\{ 65n + 4 : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a finite set. But $f \colon n \mapsto 65n + 4$ is injective, hence $f(\mathbb{N})$ is infinite. Contradiction." I guess that's not what you're looking for, however, so can you clarify what sort of proof you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

$4n^2 \equiv -1 \mod 65$ if and only if $4n^2\equiv 64 \mod 65$ if and only if $n^2\equiv 16 \mod 65$. Then for example any $n \equiv 4 \mod 65$ will give infinitely many solutions.  I realize this is not a proof by contradiction, but then you could proceed as Daniel Fischer suggested in the comments, but as he indicated it is an odd thing to do.